# How can I use TF distributed to train many estimators in a distributed environment?

Tags: distributed, tensorflow-estimator

I'm working on an optimization problem using genetic algorithms.
Let's say I have a population of 4 members.Every member generates 10 children.
The member or worker is an estimator object. I'd like to assign every 10 estimators to do some training steps on a GPU in other machine.
Considering the population_size is 4 and I have 4 GPUs, I'd like to train every 10 estimators asynchronously with a GPU from another machine.
Any ideas of how we can achieve that ?

Comment: If your workload resembles a hyperparameter search, you may want to look into libraries for doing hyperparameter search with deep networks like Ray Tune. https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tune.html

Comment: My question is not about the optimization problem itself. BTW I'm using PBT algorithm for that purpose. Actually I want to decrease the execution time by scaling my project to a distributed execution environment.

Comment: I see, Ray Tune has a PBT implementation that runs out of the box in the distributed setting (see https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tune-schedulers.html#population-based-training-pbt). However, if you already have a PBT implementation and want to run it in the distributed setting, then the PBT implementation will have to be modified and you'll need a library for distributed computing. Ray would probably be a good choice (https://github.com/ray-project/ray), but you could also communicate manually through a database like Redis as in https://github.com/openai/evolution-strategies-starter.